# ERROR: can't delete cell from tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, ios9

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update ...

I've tried almost every solution, I've found in internet - nothing actually helped.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class ViewController3: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {

    var coordinatesDictionaryInfo: [String : AnyObject] = [
        "" : ""]

    var arrayOfCoordinates = [String]()
    var arrayOfInfromation = [AnyObject]()

    func dictionaryToArray() {
        for (key, item) in coordinatesDictionaryInfo {
            arrayOfCoordinates.append(key)
            arrayOfInfromation.append(item)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.table.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dictionaryToArray()
        return self.arrayOfCoordinates.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier,
            forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = arrayOfInfromation[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.textLabel!.text = arrayOfCoordinates[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.arrayOfCoordinates.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.arrayOfInfromation.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        DVC.coordinatesDictionary = coordinatesDictionaryInfo
        //отправляем словарь на второй ViewController2
    }
}
```

Comment: First, don't call `dictionaryToArray ` inside `numberOfRowsInSection`, because it obviously has side effect on your datasource. We have no idea when it will get call. Move it to `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else.

Comment: I fixed everything by deleting item from original dictionary inside .delete function. (CoordinatesDictionaryInfo.removeValueForKey(arrayOfCoordiantes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row))